# Добавление функционала в программу с turtle

Tags: python, функции, turtle

При запуске кода и нажатии на копку паузы, черепашка рисует 3 кнопки, к которым привязаны функции и строку "PAUSES".

Помогите сделать так, чтобы при выполнении одной из функций, связанных с кнопками, кнопки стирались, и игра либо продолжалась без кнопок и строки "PAUSES", либо перезапустилась (тоже без кнопок и без строки "PAUSES"), либо завершилась и закрыла окно.

```
import turtle

sc = turtle.Screen()
sc.bgcolor("black")
sc.setup(width=1000, height=600)

pause1 = turtle.Turtle()
pause1.speed(0)
pause1.shape("square")
pause1.color("white")
pause1.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)
pause1.penup()
pause1.goto(-470, 270)
pause2 = turtle.Turtle()
pause2.speed(0)
pause2.shape("square")
pause2.color("black")
pause2.shapesize(stretch_wid=1.5, stretch_len=1.5)
pause2.penup()
pause2.goto(-470, 270)
pause3 = turtle.Turtle()
pause3.speed(0)
pause3.shape("square")
pause3.color("white")
pause3.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=0.25)
pause3.penup()
pause3.goto(-464, 270)
pause4 = turtle.Turtle()
pause4.speed(0)
pause4.shape("square")
pause4.color("white")
pause4.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=0.25)
pause4.penup()
pause4.goto(-477, 270)


def pauses(x, y):
    if -490 < x < -450 and 250 < y < 290:
        text = turtle.Turtle()
        text.speed(10)
        text.color("white")
        text.penup()
        text.hideturtle()
        text.goto(0, 120)
        text.write("PAUSE",
                   align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
        restart = turtle.Turtle()
        restart.speed(10)
        restart.shape("square")
        restart.color("orange")
        restart.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)
        restart.penup()
        restart.goto(-80, 40)
        restart2 = turtle.Turtle()
        restart2.speed(10)
        restart2.shape("square")
        restart2.color("black")
        restart2.shapesize(stretch_wid=1.5, stretch_len=1.5)
        restart2.penup()
        restart2.goto(-80, 40)
        restart3 = turtle.Turtle()
        restart3.speed(10)
        restart3.shape("circle")
        restart3.color("white")
        restart3.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)
        restart3.penup()
        restart3.goto(-80, 40)
        restart4 = turtle.Turtle()
        restart4.speed(10)
        restart4.shape("circle")
        restart4.color("black")
        restart4.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.75, stretch_len=0.75)
        restart4.penup()
        restart4.goto(-80, 40)
        restart5 = turtle.Turtle()
        restart5.left(90)
        restart5.speed(10)
        restart5.shape("triangle")
        restart5.color("white")
        restart5.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.6, stretch_len=0.45)
        restart5.penup()
        restart5.goto(-88, 40)

        resume1 = turtle.Turtle()
        resume1.speed(10)
        resume1.shape("square")
        resume1.color("orange")
        resume1.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)
        resume1.penup()
        resume1.goto(0, 40)
        resume2 = turtle.Turtle()
        resume2.speed(10)
        resume2.shape("square")
        resume2.color("black")
        resume2.shapesize(stretch_wid=1.5, stretch_len=1.5)
        resume2.penup()
        resume2.goto(0, 40)
        resume3 = turtle.Turtle()
        resume3.speed(10)
        resume3.shape("square")
        resume3.color("white")
        resume3.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)
        resume3.penup()
        resume3.goto(0, 40)
        resume4 = turtle.Turtle()
        resume4.speed(10)
        resume4.shape("triangle")
        resume4.color("black")
        resume4.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.75, stretch_len=0.75)
        resume4.penup()
        resume4.goto(-2, 40)

        home1 = turtle.Turtle()
        home1.speed(10)
        home1.shape("square")
        home1.color("orange")
        home1.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=2)
        home1.penup()
        home1.goto(80, 40)
        home2 = turtle.Turtle()
        home2.speed(10)
        home2.shape("square")
        home2.color("black")
        home2.shapesize(stretch_wid=1.5, stretch_len=1.5)
        home2.penup()
        home2.goto(80, 40)
        home3 = turtle.Turtle()
        home3.speed(10)
        home3.shape("square")
        home3.color("white")
        home3.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.8, stretch_len=0.8)
        home3.penup()
        home3.goto(80, 36)
        home4 = turtle.Turtle()
        home4.speed(10)
        home4.shape("square")
        home4.color("black")
        home4.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.5, stretch_len=0.5)
        home4.penup()
        home4.goto(80, 36)
        home5 = turtle.Turtle()
        home5.left(90)
        home5.speed(10)
        home5.shape("triangle")
        home5.color("white")
        home5.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.8, stretch_len=0.5)
        home5.penup()
        home5.goto(80, 48)
        home6 = turtle.Turtle()
        home6.left(90)
        home6.speed(10)
        home6.shape("triangle")
        home6.color("black")
        home6.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.4, stretch_len=0.25)
        home6.penup()
        home6.goto(80, 47)

        def home():
            sys.exit()

        def resume():
            text.clear()
            restart.clear()
            restart2.clear()
            restart3.clear()
            restart4.clear()
            restart5.clear()
            resume1.clear()
            resume2.clear()
            resume3.clear()
            resume4.clear()
            home1.clear()
            home2.clear()
            home3.clear()
            home4.clear()
            home5.clear()
            home6.clear()

        def restart1():
            right_player = 3
            left_player = 3
            up_player = 3
            sketch.clear()
            sketch1.clear()
            sketch2.clear()
            sketch.write("Left player : 3", align="center",
                         font=("Courier", 20, "normal"))
            sketch1.write("Right player : 3", align="center",
                          font=("Courier", 20, "normal"))
            sketch2.write("Up player : 3", align="center",
                          font=("Courier", 20, "normal"))
            text.clear()
            restart.clear()
            restart2.clear()
            restart3.clear()
            restart4.clear()
            restart5.clear()
            resume1.clear()
            resume2.clear()
            resume3.clear()
            resume4.clear()
            home1.clear()
            home2.clear()
            home3.clear()
            home4.clear()
            home5.clear()
            home6.clear()

        sc.listen()
        sc.onkeypress(home, "h")
        sc.onkeypress(resume, "p")
        sc.onkeypress(restart1, "r")


sc.listen()
turtle.onscreenclick(pauses, 1)

while True:
    sc.update()
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Для реализации подобного функционала я бы рекомендовал использовать модуль [`tkinter`]()https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html либо [`pygame`](https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/). В любом случае, если вам удастся решить эту проблему, не стесняйтесь описать решение в ответе. Удачи!

Comment: @diduk001  Под черепашкой лежит ткинтер.

Comment: @СергейКох я знаю, но по моему мнению, рисовать фигуры сразу было бы гораздо удобнее